# JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found. error on When Install HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, java-home

I'm new to the hadoop. when the process of the installation, i gave hadoop.env.sh a JAVA_HOME path, but when I'm going to execute hdfs namenode -format it says that the java_home is not set.when check it again, it also saved in the hadoop.env.sh. i can't up the hdfs because of this. explained help is much appreciated.

thank u. i've attached the screen shot for the reference as well.[hadoop.env.sh view][error message][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYpfY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you restart HDFS service after adding JAVA_HOME to hadoop-env.sh?
ALso try echoing `echo $JAVA_HOME` before running hadoop namenode format command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set environment variable correctly.

https://hadoopwala.wordpress.com/2016/07/03/java/

**Reference:** [Hadoop-Psuedo Distributed Mode](https://hadoopwala.wordpress.com/2016/07/10/hadoop-psuedo-distributed-mode/)

Hope this helps.